# I'm working on pset4 of CS50, but the blur function filters the image into (almost) all red

Tags: c, cs50

I tried this code to do the "blur" function in pset4 of CS50 course, but it doesn't work in a qay that the output is black and red.

I tried to print out avgRed avgBlue and avgGreen and in fact almost every pixel had a lot of red and very little blue and green such as (53, 2, 2) or (8, 0, 0), something like this.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE imageCopy[height][width];
    //imageCopy = malloc(width * height * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));


    float avgRed;
    float avgBlue;
    float avgGreen;

    //if (imageCopy != NULL)
    //{

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            imageCopy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

   // }

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {

            avgRed = 0;
            avgBlue = 0;
            avgGreen = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            for(int x = i - 1; x <= i + 1; x++)
            {

                    for(int y = j - 1; y <= j + 1; y++)
                    {
                            if(x >= 0 && x < height && y >= 0 && y < width)
                            {


                                avgRed += imageCopy[x][y].rgbtRed;
                                avgBlue += imageCopy[x][y].rgbtBlue;
                                avgGreen += imageCopy[x][y].rgbtGreen;

                                counter++;

                            }

                    }



            }

            avgRed = round(avgRed / counter);
            avgBlue = round(avgRed / counter);
            avgGreen = round(avgRed / counter);

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = avgBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = avgGreen;

            
        }


    }




    //free(imageCopy);
    return;
}
```

But when I try to filter an image it gets all red... I've seen that other people also have got this problem, but their solutions didn't help me in any way. Is there someone who could help me?

Please, let me know if I'm doing everything wrong or it's just something written in the wrong place or forgotten.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks weird to use `avgRed` for all calculatons here:

```c
            avgRed = round(avgRed / counter);
            avgBlue = round(avgRed / counter);
            avgGreen = round(avgRed / counter);
```

You may want:

```c
            avgRed = round(avgRed / counter);
            avgBlue = round(avgBlue / counter);
            avgGreen = round(avgGreen / counter);
```

Comment: Oh my… how didn’t I notice I used three times avgRed XD